# Javascript : global variable passed-by-reference on stored function

Tags: javascript, parameters, reference

I got something that I just don't understand with the javascript interpreter.
When a variable is passed in parameter on a stored function, it seems that it's passed by reference, and not by value.

Here the PoC :

```js
var nb = 10;
var varfunc;

function myFunc(a) {
  console.log("after = " + a);
}

console.log("before = " + nb);
varfunc = function() {
  myFunc(nb)
};

nb = nb + 1;

varfunc();
```

I expected to have "10" value for both outputs.
How can I actually pass the "nb" value when the "set" instruction is executed on the "varfunc" variable ?

I encountered this problem when setting the "onClick" property where I linked a function with a global variable passed as parameter :

```
var global_var = 0;
...
function oneFunction(){
  var delImg = document.createElement("img");
  delImg.src = "images/delete.gif";
  delImg.onclick = function(){
                     deleteFG(global_var);
                   };
...
}
...
oneFunction();
```

When the "onClick" event is triggered, the "deleteFG()" function is called with the current value of "global_var", and not with the value it was when set instruction for "onClick" has been processed.

I found a dirty solution by creating a temp variable:

```
var global_var = 0;
...
function oneFunction(){
  var delImg = document.createElement("img");
  delImg.src = "images/delete.gif";
  var tmp_var = global_var;
  delImg.onclick = function(){
                   deleteFG(tmp_var);
                 };  
...
}
...
oneFunction();
```

Can someone please explain ? :)

Comment: Given the line `nb = nb + 1;` why exactly would you expect the second log output to have shown `10` instead of `11`?

Comment: +1 to @Pointy. And another question would be: why are you passing global variables through functions if they already can access them? Even if the usage of global variables is highly discouraged, but since you are using them, why do you need to pass them as arguments of functions?

Comment: @quirimmo The purpose of passing global variable (instead of directly reading it) was to actually pass the current value of this variable at the moment when the "varfunc = function(){...}" is processed.

Comment: @Dreaky OK, well that's not how JavaScript works. The mention of `nb` in the function declaration does not "capture" the current value of the variable, at least as the function is written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected to have "10" value for both outputs.

First, you change `nb` to `11`.

Then you call `varfunc` which reads the value of `nb` (which you've already changed) and passes it (`11`) to `myFunc`.

This has nothing to do with references.

---

If you want to capture the value at the time you create the function, you must copy it to another variable **at that point**.

You can use a closure to do that (I use an IIFE to create one in this example).

```js
var nb = 10;
var varfunc;

function myFunc(a) {
  console.log("after = " + a);
}

console.log("before = " + nb);

varfunc = function(copy_of_nb) {
  return function() {
    myFunc(copy_of_nb);
  };
}(nb);

nb = nb + 1;

varfunc();

console.log("finally = " + nb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work. Since `nb` is a global variable it won't be captured when you create that function, but when the function is actually run.

Basically when you run that function, that is when the variables actually take effect.

The code below basically wraps that function within another function that runs on that line of code and passes in the current value of `nb` instead of the value when you actually run the `varfunc` function.

```js
var nb = 10;
var varfunc;

function myFunc(a)
{
  console.log("after = "+a);
}

console.log("before = "+nb);
var num2 = nb ;
varfunc= (function(a) {
  return function(){
    myFunc(a)
  }
})(nb);

nb = nb + 1;

varfunc();
```